# What are the trade offs when choosing a long term bond future to trade?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, futures, trading, bond-futures

It seems that when trading long term bonds *** and choosing between the two offerings on CME one is presented with a [Scylla and Charybdis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis) decision.

**1. VOLATILITY CONSISTENCY:** [Ultra U.S. Treasury Bond Futures (UB)](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/us-treasury/ultra-t-bond_quotes_globex.html) have a more consistent volatility profile given its basket of deliverable is homogeneous and you can expect roughly a 25 year duration. On the other hand ZB has a variable duration, from 17-22 years.

**2. SKEW:** [U.S. Treasury Bond Futures (ZB)](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/us-treasury/30-year-us-treasury-bond_quotes_globex.html) have a preferable skew profile.

***So one would prefer leveraging ZB to achieve the volatility of UB.***

Am I reading the trade offs correctly? Is there anything that I'm missing?

*** Long biased trading strategy. Outright positioning. Position duration 6-24 hours.